# Convert static query in Mysql to Dynamic

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some problems understanding dynamic query in Mysql. I need to convert my example query from static to dynamic. In the example i have 2 schemas and i already know the names. But i need to create a dynamic query that works if i don't know the schemas'name and number. Can i get an hint on how to do it or what i need to study?

```
SELECT MIN(tmp.DATE47) as DATE47,
   MIN(tmp.HOUR47) as HOUR47,
   MIN(tmp.DATE49) as DATE49,
   MIN(tmp.HOUR49) as HOUR49

FROM (SELECT DATEIN AS DATE47, HOURIN AS HOUR47, NULL AS DATE49, NULL AS HOUR49
 FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
     UNION ALL
 SELECT NULL AS DATE47, NULL AS HOUR47, HOURIN AS DATE49, HOURIN AS HOUR49
 FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)tmp
```

Comment: Where schemas names are taken from, and in what format? What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: It is reasonable to select MIN() of values in subqueries too - this will decrease the size of processed data twice.

Comment: Do you understand that DATExx AND HOURxx may be taken from different source rows?

Comment: I need to do it with subqueries, the tables and the columns are all the same in every schema. The only variables things are the numbers of schema and their names.

Comment: You need to create a stored procedure which builds the query you want to execute at runtime. You cannot use a variable for the schema directly with sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick example on prepared statements:

```
SET @statement = 'SELECT MIN(tmp.DATE47) as DATE47,
   MIN(tmp.HOUR47) as HOUR47,
   MIN(tmp.DATE49) as DATE49,
   MIN(tmp.HOUR49) as HOUR49

FROM (SELECT DATEIN AS DATE47, HOURIN AS HOUR47, NULL AS DATE49, NULL AS HOUR49
 FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
     UNION ALL
 SELECT NULL AS DATE47, NULL AS HOUR47, HOURIN AS DATE49, HOURIN AS HOUR49
 FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)tmp;'

PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
```

Now you can use this statement to query `schema1` and `schema2`:

```
EXECUTE stmt;
```

If you need to use, i.e., `schema3` and `schema2` do:

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
PREPARE stmt FROM REPLACE(@statement,'schema1','schema3');
```

and start doing: `EXECUTE stmt;` again....

Of course this would be handled in a stored procedure, more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you this is a good example to start learning.